# Angularjs Form validation How can i get values inside Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

This is my Html Part

```
    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>

                        <!-- NAME -->
                        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required>
                            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
                        </div>
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.submitForm = function (userForm) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(userForm);
        if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
            debugger;
            console.log($scope.userForm.name);
            alert('our form is amazing');
            console.log($scope.userForm);
        }

    };
```

Here why i'm not able to get values from Html to Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO NOT define parameter for function. Use $scope.user in controller if you want the value of user and for getting form, use $scope.userForm in your controller.

```
$scope.submitForm = function () {
   $scope.master = angular.copy($scope.userForm);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no arguments passed in submitForm function from ng-submit!  And log $scope.user in submitForm() & see what comes inside! If nothing comes, initialize $scope.user ={}; outside the submitForm(). Then you can get inside submitForm function $scope.user.name 
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code. i think you forgot to pass value in button event

if you don't want to change your code you can find the text box value in $scope.master(same in your code)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(user)" novalidate>

  <!-- NAME -->
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required>
    <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.submitForm = function (userForm) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(userForm);
        if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
            debugger;
            console.log($scope.userForm.name);
            alert(userForm.name)
            alert('our form is amazing');
            console.log($scope.userForm);
        }

    };
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```